# Can't get data with http on Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm beginner on Angular, I've a problem with a request http on server.
Local request in file works fine, but not on server, I don't understand.

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, HttpModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DataService } from './time/time.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
          <button (click)="displayData()">Click</button>
          <div>Time : {{ data | json }}</div>
          `,
  providers: [DataService]
})
export class AppComponent {
        data: any[];

        constructor(public dataService : DataService) { }

        displayData() {
                this.dataService.getDatas().subscribe(
                        r => this.data = r,
                );
        }
}
```

**time.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class DataService {

        constructor(public _http: Http) { }

        getDatas() {
                //return this._http.get('/app/test.json')
                return this._http.get('http://date.jsontest.com')
                        .map(res => res.json());
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Edit : I've an error on console.

```
Error: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:1:3
caused by: [Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x805e0006 (<unknown>)"
location: "JS frame :: http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js
/dist/zone.js :: scheduleTask :: line 1645"  data: no]
```

Comment: Did you try changing `http` with `https` in your url?

Comment: What issue, you are getting? try to console `r => {this.data = r; console.log(this.data)},` see what you are getting..

Comment: @echonax Does'nt works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'd just need to initialise the data variable in your class because you're accessing it before the asycn operation is done.

```
export class AppComponent {

    private data = {}; // initialise the data here

}
```

The rest is ok .

Here is the plunker `http://plnkr.co/edit/zv23KWlmHaDR3bYnODR1?p=preview`

If you want , you can make it more Typescript friendly :

```
export interface MyDate{
  time: string;
  milliseconds_since_epoch: number;
  date: string;
}

export class  AppComponent{
     private data :MyDate = {}; // initialise the data here

}


 getDatas() :Observable<MyDate>{
       //return this._http.get('/app/test.json')
    return this._http.get('http://date.jsontest.com')
                    .map(res => res.json());
  }
```